# upgrade manually prestashop from 1.7.4 to 1.7.6 causes an error

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm following this guide https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/keeping-up-to-date/upgrade/ in order to upgrade my prestashop 1.7.4 to 1.7.6

but when upgrading the db, this is what happens:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PrestaShop\\PrestaShop\\Core\\ContainerBuilder' not found in /web/htdocs/website/home/config/bootstrap.php:34: /web/htdocs/website/home/install/upgrade/upgrade.php
```

I guess  something wrong with composer happened. Any hints?

Comment: try to update vendor folder, with the last one

Comment: nope, that doesn't work. But look what I've found: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/14595